# sometimes VS2008 take long time to compile

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, compilation

I have a huge C++ solution.

When I change one class and compile
In some cases compilation (and linkage) takes little time (less than a second)
But in some cases it takes ages (more that 30 seconds)

I do not understand why this happens. 
The huge difference in performance suggests that something can be done in order to maximize the number of times the compiler is fast.

Any ideas?

Comment: The compiler can see your code. We cannot.

Comment: its a 10,000,000 lines of code project...

Comment: Then I guess you need to do some work to present us information that allows us to help

Comment: I cann't. What I am looking for is some common settings Known to improve compiler performance. Like some king of cache size that should be increased for large models, or disabling some checks, or doing some preprocess that can be done only once...

Comment: Nobody can give you good advice without knowing what the problem is.

Comment: Hmm, getting a 30 second rebuild for a 10 MLoc program is little to complain about.  Incremental linking is crucial to get down to 1 second.  Sometimes you do run out of increments and you get a full link.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a class `A` and you add **a new data member** to it in the header file. Then `A` has to be recompiled. If `B` contains `A` as a member then `B` has to be recompiled as well. If `C` has a member `B` then `C` also has to be recompiled and so on. A change in `A` can have a [domino effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_effect). A seemingly tiny change (adding a new data member to a class) **can result in recompiling the entire project.**

On the other hand, if you make substantial changes to implementation of **a member function** of `A` in the implementation source file (`*.cpp`) then, chances are, only `A` has to be recompiled but nothing else. This is **likely to be very fast.**

If you wish to understand what triggers the domino effect and what doesn't, I suggest you read *Item 31: Minimize compilation dependecies between files* in [Effective C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876) and Items 26-30 on *Minimizing Compile-time Dependencies* in [Exceptional C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201615622).

**There is no magic setting of the compiler that will make the compilation fast.** Only your understanding and careful coding can help.

Comment: I'm talking about the same scenario. The compiler compiles only one class. and sometimes it take less than a second, and sometimes more than 30 seconds

Comment: @DuduArbel Please read those items in the books I linked. Then *it is your task* to figure out how to fix it in your code. Nobody can tell you more without seeing your code.